# Automatically forward emails manually moved to a specific folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

The scenario:  I plan to use a single generic email inbox to recieve emails from suppliers when they have a query.  There are over 2000 suppliers.  The suppliers are supported by 6 specialist teams.  Unfortunately 3 of these teams are not within my email domain, they are supported by a third-party.
The inbound emails could be from any supplier, with various subject lines.
Possible solution:  I currently believe that each email will have to be manually reviewed by our core team to determine which team should handle the query.  Once they know, they will move the email into 1 of the 6 folders set up for each of the 6 teams to manage.  For 3 of these teams I was hoping to automatically forward the emails when they are moved into the related team folder.
Question:  Is the possible solution thinking reasonable, or should I be thinking about this differently?  If it is a good strategy, how can I set up the rule(s) accordingly?

Comment: I'm afraid that Outlook doesn't have such a built-in option to realize this.

Comment: These reviewers can directly forward emails to team members.

Comment: I’d be somewhat surprised if you couldn’t handle this in VBA somehow.  A slightly different approach: use VBA to create six buttons that do the appropriate thing, whatever that is.  (I’ve never used VBA in Outlook, so I don’t know whether this is feasible or practical.)

Comment: Thank you both for your replies and help.  At least I now know there is no obvious answer.